# how to make a responsive height for img in firefox (safari, chrome working)

Tags: media-queries, css

I have a problem [here](http://isobike.aktualnitest.cz/)

The problem area is two images on the right side of this website using `max-height:50%;` is not working in Firefox.

Open the page in Chrome or Safari and it works but then open it in Firefox and it does not work.

I have tried changing the `div id=rightcontent` to `% width`, but still not working.

```
#total #content {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -108px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height 

*/
}
#total #content #leftcontent {
    position:relative;
    width:60%;
    padding-left:10%;
    float:left;
}
#total #content #rightcontent {
    position:relative;
    max-width:237px;
    float:right;
}
#total #content #rightcontent img {
    position:relative;
    max-height:50% !important;
    float:right;
    max-width:100% !important;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftcontent">
        <h1>Kola <strong>STEVENS</strong> nejen prodáváme,<br/>ale hlavně na nich jezdíme.</h1>
        <p><a href="" title="Chci jezdit na kole STEVENS" id="chci"></a></p>
    </div>   
    <div id="rightcontent">
        <div id="tst">
            <img src="img/right1.png" />
            <img src="img/right2.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090989/firefox-ignores-percent-height-on-image) and I think it's a firefox way of handleing image sizes.

Your code is okay but if I was writing the code, I would use an image-wrapper for images to make it browsers cross-compatible. If you resize the page after loading in chrome you can see your images are no longer looking like before.

My solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaTam/)):

```
<div id="rightcontent">
    <div id="tst">
        <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="img/right1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="img/right2.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JanDiehel If you think your problem is solved, please provide an answer for your question and mark it as accepted so other people can use it in similar situations.